# need htaccess help in setting up rewritebase

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a localhost environment and a test server environment. I write all my code locally and on occasion push the changes to the testing server. My code needs to be intelligent enough to know where it is being run so that it can call on appropriate url (local or test).

my local environment URL is "my.local" and test environment url is "test.somedomain.com"

I need to be able to set a baserewrite or something that adjusts itself according to the url the code is on.

Any help?

Comment: Check this page for redirect samples using .htaccess file: http://perishablepress.com/press/2006/01/10/stupid-htaccess-tricks/#redirects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have set up your `virtualhost` & `DocumentRoot`

All you have to do for your documentroot is:

```
RewriteBase /
```

in your per directory `.htaccess` residing in your `DocumentRoot`.

For other folders, you will have to set up an [`Alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias)(Context: server config, virtual host), a `mod_alias` directive.

> Example:
>
> Alias /xyz /abc/def

And use [`RewriteBase`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) directive in your per directory `.htaccess` 
Example from: [`RewriteBase`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase)**:**

```
#  /abc/def/.htaccess -- per-dir config file for directory /abc/def
#  Remember: /abc/def is the physical path of /xyz, i.e., the server
#            has a 'Alias /xyz /abc/def' directive e.g.
#

RewriteEngine On

#  let the server know that we were reached via /xyz and not
#  via the physical path prefix /abc/def
RewriteBase   /xyz

#  now the rewriting rules
RewriteRule   ^oldstuff\.html$  newstuff.html
```